# How to combine a multiMatchQuery with a boolQuery using Spring Data Elastic Search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using a multi match query like so:

```
var builder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(search, "projectName", "jobNumber");
var query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
   .withQuery(builder)
   .withPageable(pageable)
   .build();
var result = searchOperations.search(query, Foo.class);
```

Now I need to make sure that the `_id` field also matches the `FooId` field. How do I create a query to do that and combine it with my multi match query?

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both clauses are mandatory, you can combine them using `must` method of `BoolQueryBuilder`:

```java
var builder = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                 .must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(search, "projectName", "jobNumber"))
                 .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id", fooId));
var query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
               .withQuery(builder)
               .withPageable(pageable)
               .build();
var result = searchOperations.search(query, Foo.class);
```

Or you can define the clause by id as a filter having the same result:

```java
var builder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(search, "projectName", "jobNumber");
var filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id", fooId)
var query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
               .withQuery(builder)
               .withFilter(filter)
               .withPageable(pageable)
               .build();
var result = searchOperations.search(query, Foo.class);
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73652415/how-to-combine-a-term-query-with-a-suggestion-using-spring-data-elastic-search